# Add Boostrap 4 Alpha to Yii 2 advanced template with composer?

Tags: php, yii, yii2-advanced-app, bootstrap-4

How to add the Boostrap 4 alpha's into a `yii2-app-advanced` app, using `composer` and making it a dependancy?

I've tried editing `vendor/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap`, and adding `4.*` in it's `composer.json` on line `22`, but no avail:

```
"bower-asset/bootstrap": "3.3.* | 3.2.* | 3.1.* | 4.*"
```

It being an asset bundle or compatible with the current one (`v3`), is not that important to me. Just adding it properly and distributing it over my git repo.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to your `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.1.0@dev",
        "bower-asset/bootstrap": "~4.0.0@alpha",
        "bower-asset/jquery": "2.2.*"
    }
}
```

It worked for me. [Source](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap/issues/77#issuecomment-238702371).